# MATLAB - adding number on text file

Tags: matlab

I need to use "importdata" to run a script, but my file has more columns at the bottom than at the top, like this:

**Example1**

```
2 2 3 2
2 2 1 1
1 0
2 4
1 1 2 200000 80000
```

It starts with 4 columns, and ends with 5), so when I use importdata, it makes a matrix with 4 columns, damaging my file. What I wanted to do is add any number at the end of the first data row (or second text row), preferentially a 0, to make it read my file as a 5-column matrix, like this:

**Example1**

```
2 2 3 2 0
2 2 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 4 0 0 0
1 1 2 200000 80000
```

The zeros in the other columns are, as I understand, the result of the "importdata" in a 5-column matrix, I don't need to write them too. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `textscan` to read in your data. Here's how to read in your file:

```
fid = fopen('example.txt');
mat = textscan(fid,'%d %d %d %d %d','CollectOutput', 1);
mat = mat{1}; % accesses matrix from cell array
mat(isnan(mat)) = 0; % sets NaN values to 0
fclose(fid);
```

And the results:

```
mat =

           2           2           3           2           0
           2           2           1           1           0
           1           0           0           0           0
           2           4           0           0           0
           1           1           2      200000       80000
```

You can then save this a new file like this:

```
fid = fopen('newfile.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%d %d %d %d %d\r\n', mat);
fclose(fid);
```

and read it in with `importdata`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood the question, but I think he wants to use importdata because it's included in a script he doesn't want to modify and was looking to modify the text file instead.

Comment: Yes, it's precisely for this reason.
I have tried the code you sent, but the results were:

2 2 1 2 1...  

1 2 2 0 4...  

1 1 3 1 0...  

0 2 1 2 1...  

0 0 200000 0 0...  

0 0 0 80000 0...  

So, it kind of transposed my matrix, and left it worse than before. What is the problem?

Comment: @user2512293 Just stop at `mat`, isn't that what you want?